# web3 [object, Promise] error that .then and await does not work

Tags: javascript, html, web3js, binance-smart-chain

```
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
...
    <script>
      const web3 = new Web3('https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443');
      const version = web3.version.api;
      const burnAddress = "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dead";

      //jQuery pull of contractABI from getAddress
      function pullData() {
        getAddress = $('input[name="contractAddress"]').val();
        getJSONString = 'https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=' + getAddress + '&apikey' + API_KEY;
        $.getJSON(getJSONString, function(data) {
          contractABI = JSON.parse(data.result);
          //document.getElementById("json").innerHTML = "JSON: " + JSON.stringify(contractABI);
          myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, getAddress);
          decimals = tokenContract.methods.decimals().call(); // promise error
          document.getElementById("decimals").innerHTML = "Decimals: " + decimals;

        });
        document.getElementById("addy").innerHTML = "Address: " + getAddress;
       }
     </script>
```

Seems like no matter what I do I can never get a number to populate, and JSON.stringify() does not show anything either.

Yes a form input is passed in calls pullData()
Then that address pulls an ABI (that works)
I can create a new contract instance, I can pull as many [object, Promise] as the `<p id's>` can handle on any of "my methods" from read the docs (also yes, the console.log(decimals) works too, but none show numbers ever in HTML.
I did search here, what am I missing?

Code above is from my vanilla test HTML page.

Comment: there's no then or await in that code - and it seems there doesn't need to be since you're using the $.getJSON callback - perhaps there's an error in the request - have you checked the browser console?

Comment: yeah i even tried the $.ajax on those, it didn't seem to work well, looks like I got the answers I was looking for below. The console.logs were showing promise values resolved after some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about this API, but I think you need to change this:

```js
decimals = tokenContract.methods.decimals().call(); // promise error
document.getElementById("decimals").innerHTML = "Decimals: " + decimals;
```

To something like this:

```js
tokenContract.methods.decimals().call().then(decimals => {
  document.getElementById("decimals").innerHTML = "Decimals: " + decimals;
});
```

Perhaps reading up on [Promise.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) might help you out. After that, look up async/await.

Comment: This was the solid answer... I thank you a million and one times over!

Comment: Also thanks, for the link to Promise.then() I haven't used JS in ages.

Comment: No problem! Glad you got it working. Promises are much easier to use these days with async/await, but it seemed to me that using .then() was the shortest way to get the solution this time.